# Custom attributes added in api2.xml are not visible in admin

Tags: rest, magento

I am trying to create a custom API in Magento 1.14 by following [this blog post](http://www.ipragmatech.com/customize-magento-rest-api/). Neither an error nor the response is getting displayed. I am able to get the REST Role for Custom API in Admin Panel, but I couldn't get REST Attribute. How can I get it from the following file?

Folder Structure:
Folder Structure of custom module][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caQxL.png)

Magento/app/code/local/Ipragmatech/Gtm/etc/api2.xml
[api2.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40B4T.png)

Magento/app/code/local/Ipragmatech/Gtm/etc/config.xml
[config.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDEBh.png)

Magento/app/code/local/Ipragmatech/Ipragmatech/Gtm/Model/Catalog/Api2/Product/Rest/Guest/V1.php
[V1.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5Afq.png)

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: Yeah I can... I have followed the same steps as mentioned in the above mentioned link. But Setting a REST Attributes for Custom API is not reflecting in Magento Admin.

Comment: I have attached the screenshots of my code. Can anyone help me?